# perl Digest add addfile computes different SHA1 digest

Tags: perl, sha1, digest

perl `Digest` module computes different SHA1 digest for `add` and `addfile` functions.
I have created binary random data using `/dev/urandom`

running on ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
```

output from the script

```
$ perl t.pl sha1 a.tmp
doesntwork      da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
works           ee49451434cffe001a568090c86f16f076677af5
$ openssl dgst -sha1 a.tmp
SHA1(a.tmp)= ee49451434cffe001a568090c86f16f076677af5
```

following in my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use Digest;

sub doesntwork {
    my ($datafile, $hashfun) = @_;
    open(my $fh, "<", $datafile ) or die "error: Can't open '$datafile', $!\n";
    binmode($fh);
    read($fh, my $data, -s $datafile);
    close($fh);

    $hashfun->add($data);
    my $hashval = $hashfun->digest();

    return unpack('H*', $hashval);
}

sub works {
    my ($datafile, $hashfun) = @_;
    open(my $fh, "<", $datafile ) or die "error: Can't open '$datafile', $!\n";
    binmode($fh);

    $hashfun->addfile($fh);
    my $hashval = $hashfun->digest();

    close($fh);

    return unpack('H*', $hashval);
}

###############################################################################
(@ARGV >= 2) or die "usage: perl $0 algo datafile\n";
my ($algo, $datafile) = @ARGV;

my $hashfun;
switch($algo) {
    case "md5"    {$hashfun = Digest->new("MD5"    );}
    case "sha1"   {$hashfun = Digest->new("SHA-1"  );}
    case "sha256" {$hashfun = Digest->new("SHA-256");}
    case "sha512" {$hashfun = Digest->new("SHA-512");}
    else          {die "error: invalid algorithm '$algo'\n"}
}

print "doesntwork\t", doesntwork( $datafile, $hashfun ), "\n";
print "works     \t", works     ( $datafile, $hashfun ), "\n";
```

I would like `add` function to work, as I want to compute it on buffered data, not from file data. Possible `add` treats data as text, while for `addfile`, `binmod` on file handle makes it use binary data, if so how can I make `add` to treat buffer as binary data.

Edited post to print size of the data read--

```
    $ stat -c "%n %s" a.tmp
    a.tmp 671088640

    $ openssl dgst -sha1 a.tmp
    SHA1(a.tmp)= 7dfcced1b0c8864e6a20b2daa63de7ffc1cd7a26

    #### Works
    $ perl -W -MDigest -e 'open(my $fh, "<", "a.tmp") or die "cant open $!\n";
    > binmode($fh);
    > my $hf = Digest->new("SHA-1");
    > $hf->addfile($fh);
    > print unpack("H*", $hf->digest()),"\n";
    > close($fh);'
    7dfcced1b0c8864e6a20b2daa63de7ffc1cd7a26

    #### Doesnt Work
    $ perl -W -MDigest -e 'open(my $fh, "<", "a.tmp") or die "cant open $!\n";
    > binmode($fh);
    > read($fh, my $data, -s "a.tmp") or die "cant read $!\n";
    > close($fh);
    > printf("## data.length=%d,file.length=%d\n",length($data),-s "a.tmp");
    > length($data)==(-s "a.tmp") or die "couldnt read all the data";
    > my $hf = Digest->new("SHA-1");
    > $hf->add($data);
    > print unpack("H*", $hf->digest()),"\n";'
    ## data.length=671088640,file.length=671088640
    9eecafd368a50fb240e0388e3c84c0c94bd6cc2a
```

Also tried according to Fred's answer

```
    $ perl -W -MDigest -e '
    > open(my $fh, "<", "a.tmp") or die "cant open $!\n";
    > binmode($fh);
    > my $size = -s "a.tmp";
    > my $got = read($fh, my $data, $size) or die "cant read $!\n";
    > print "##read $got bytes, size=$size\n";
    > my $done = $size - $got;
    > print "done=$done, size=$size, got=$got\n";
    > until(!$done) {
    >   $got   = read($fh, my $newdata, $done);
    >   $done -= $got ;
    >   $data .= $newdata;
    >   print "##read1 $got bytes, size=$size, done=$done\n";
    > }
    > close($fh);
    > printf("## data.length=%d,file.length=%d\n",length($data),-s "a.tmp");
    > length($data)==(-s "a.tmp") or die "couldnt read all the data";
    > my $hf = Digest->new("SHA-1");
    > $hf->add($data);
    > print unpack("H*", $hf->digest()),"\n";'
    ##read 671088640 bytes, size=671088640
    done=0, size=671088640, got=671088640
    ## data.length=671088640,file.length=671088640
    9eecafd368a50fb240e0388e3c84c0c94bd6cc2a
```

Comment: `add` always expects bytes

Comment: The code works fine. `read` probably didn't return the whole file. Did it?

Comment: `binmode` doesn't make a file handle "use binary data". It makes reading from the file handle return the file contents unchanged.

Comment: edited post to print size of the data read, it says whole file is read.

Answer (score 1):

You have yet to provide data that produces the problem, but I cannot replicate your problems using the Perl script as the input.

Here's the definition of `addfile`:

```
sub addfile {
    my ($self, $handle) = @_;

    my $n;
    my $buf = "";

    while (($n = read($handle, $buf, 4*1024))) {
        $self->add($buf);
    }
    unless (defined $n) {
    require Carp;
    Carp::croak("Read failed: $!");
    }

    $self;
}
```

Your claim that `addfile` works and `add` doesn't makes much sense. I suppose there could be a bug in the module when it comes to handling long strings, but it's far more likely that you're passing different inputs to the module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the return value from `read`. There is no guarantee that you have read the full contents of the file.

`read` in perl is generally implemented as a call to underlying system call `fread`. When you use low level reads like this you must test the return value
to see if you got as much as you asked for.

```
$size = -s $datafile ; 
$got = read($fh, my $data, $size);
$done = $size - $got ; 
until ( $done ) {
     $got = read($fh, my $newdata, $done ); 
     $done -= $got ; 
     $data .= $mydata ;     
}
```

That's just off the top of my head and probably has a glaring fencepost error. This is why I avoid using read whenever possible. See, http://perltricks.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string for some less painful ways to do this.

Comment: edited post with update to script as per your suggestion, it never goes on `until` loop as all data is read in first `read` call

Comment: That's insane code. `my $data; 1 while read($fh, $data, 64*1024, length($data));`